# Grouping Column Without Breaking The Sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, dense-rank

The main objective is to group the rows following **Amount** Column sequentially so that, if there is any different value between the 2 same values, they will be numbered separately.
This is the raw data here:

```
SELECT Area, DateA, DateB, Amount
FROM (VALUES
    ('ABC', '2019-08-18', '2019-08-18 00:07:47.000', 3.75),
    ('ABC','2019-08-19', '2019-08-19 00:08:47.000', 3.75),
    ('ABC','2019-08-20', '2019-08-20 00:09:47.000', 3.65),
    ('ABC','2019-08-21', '2019-08-21 00:09:57.000', 3.75))
    AS FeeCollection(Area, DateA, DateB, Amount)
```

I've tried this but, I don't know the real matter to number in a special way.

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Area, Amount)
```

This is the sample result I want to achieve. I'm looking for simple logic to do it. Using cursor or while looping will not be efficient for me.

[image]

Comment: I'm not at a PC but I think you need: `OVER (PARTITION BY DateA ORDER BY area, amount)`

Comment: @AlanBurstein aggregate functions over partitioning with DateA column might give some unrelated values. But I appreciate the method.

Comment: Yep - I was guessing. Glad you got this sorted our.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you want. I use `LAG` to get the value of the prior row in a CTE, and then use a windowed `COUNT` to reduce the value of `ROW_NUMBER` by 1 for each row with the same consecutive value for `amount`:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT Area,
           DateA,
           DateB,
           Amount,
           LAG(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY Area ORDER BY DateA) AS PrevAmount
    FROM (VALUES
        ('ABC', '2019-08-18', '2019-08-18 00:07:47.000', 3.75),
        ('ABC','2019-08-19', '2019-08-19 00:08:47.000', 3.75),
        ('ABC','2019-08-20', '2019-08-20 00:09:47.000', 3.65),
        ('ABC','2019-08-21', '2019-08-21 00:09:57.000', 3.75))
        AS FeeCollection(Area, DateA, DateB, Amount))
SELECT Area,
       DateA,
       DateB,
       Amount,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Area ORDER BY DateA) - 
       COUNT(CASE Amount WHEN PrevAmount THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY Area ORDER BY DateA
                                                           ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Number
FROM CTE
ORDER BY DateA;
```

I did assume your `PARTITION BY` clause, which you may need to change/remove/move to the `ORDER BY`. As we had only one value for `Area` was impossible to know what the value should be when it changes.

Comment: The Area Column is not the same for all values, but this method does distinguish correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this using `lag()` and a cumulative sum, but looking like:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when prev_amount = amount then 0 else 1 end) over
           (partition by area order by datea) as number
from (select t.*,
             lag(amount) over (partition by area order by datea) as prev_amount
      from t
     ) t;
```